# How to concatenate 2 columns from another table to 1 table?

Tags: mysql, concatenation, multiple-columns, concat-ws

I'm setting up a new database and I need to `concatenate` 2 columns from another table to 1 column.

I've tried it with `HeidiSQL`. Is there a mistake in my code?

```
UPDATE annotationfile
SET LABSDTM = CONCAT_WS('T',importfile.Collection_Date, importfile.Collection_Time)  ;
```

This is the error message:

> "Unknown column 'importfile.Collection_Date'" in field list.

I am for 100% sure that the field list is actually there.

Comment: You should review Multiple-table syntax: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html. At present your query is not accessing the table import

Answer (score 1):

You need to join import , your query should look more like this

```
UPDATE annotationfile join import on something 
SET LABSDTM = CONCAT_WS('T',importfile.Collection_Date, importfile.Collection_Time) 
;
```